# Python - my newly created class instance is lost

Tags: python

I am preparing for a Python exam and I was experimenting with classes and class methods, and In the following code I create a class instance that is there, but I can't retrieve it, even though it shows in the class' **dict**
Here's the code:

```
class Watch:
   instances = []

def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model
    self.eng = ""
    self.__class__.instances.append(self.model) 

@classmethod
def create_new_watch(cls, model, eng):
    if eng.isalnum() and len(eng) < 40:
        watch = cls(model)
        watch.eng = eng
    else: 
        raise ValueError("Invalid engraving")
    if len(watch.eng) > 0:
        print("Your new watch model {} was created".format(watch.model))
        print("Your new watch will have the following engraving {}".format(watch.eng))
    else:
        print("Your new watch model {} was created".format(watch.model))
    return watch

object1 = Watch.create_new_watch("model S", "Newengraving")

def create_object(object2, model, eng):
    try: 
        object2 = Watch.create_new_watch(model, eng)
        print(object2)
        print(isinstance(object2, Watch))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print("the object was successfully created")

create_object("Watch4", "modello T", "Anotherengraving")

#this works, object 1 is an instance of the class Watch
print(isinstance(object1, Watch))

#but here it raises an exception saying that object 2 is not specified
print(isinstance(object2, Watch))

#but 2 instances of the class are present, so why isinstance(object2, Watch) raises an exception?
print(Watch.__dict__)
'''
```

My object1 is there and `isinstance(object1, Watch)` returns `true`, but the same function on object2 raises an error, even tho I can see that a second class instances has been created in the class.

Under which name has my object2 been created?

Comment: It seems that your ```object2``` is not global but its local to ```create_object()```

Answer (score 1):

You `object2` only exist in the scope of your function.